# NextJS got 413 "Entity too large" response

Tags: next.js, formidable

I'm using formidable to deal with file upload stuff in my NextJS project. To use formidable inside NextJS I have to set `bodyParser` to false for the upload API cos formidable need to get the file from Stream. Everything went well in the development environment(No matter how big the file is). But I'll get a 413 response from the production when I try to upload a larger file(about 10mb, actually not big at all).

In my opinion, the bodyParser shouldn't block the bigger file even if I didn't set a `sizeLimit` property cos the bodyParser itself was set to false.

Does anyone get some ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried increasing `bodyParser.sizeLimit` anyway, and see if that fixes the issue? Also, where are you hosting the production website?

Comment: I'm in exactly the same boat.  Did you resolve this?

Comment: try to find out the difference between prod and local

Comment: i got same issues like this. that's because vercel has limit on payload request

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured out that it's Vercel limits the payload size for the request body.

> **Serverless Function Payload Size Limit**
>
> The maximum payload size for the request body or the response body of
> a [Serverless
> Function](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions)
> is **4.5 MB**.
>
> If a Serverless Function receives a payload in excess of the limit it
> will return an error **→ 413: FUNCTION_PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE**.

Reference doc: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#serverless-function-size